# Orchard site trowing exception when connected to SQL DB, any ideas?

Tags: orchardcms

I have an Orchard site with a SQL DB, when I try to access the site the following error happen:

Server Error in '/' Application.

None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'BodyLogic.Physicians.Services.PhysicianService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'BodyLogic.LegacyDb.Services.Repositories.Physicians.IPhysicianRepository physicianRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(BodyLogic.LegacyDb.Services.Repositories.Physicians.IPhysicianRepository, BodyLogic.LegacyDb.Services.DtoConverters.IDtoConverter)'.

When I delete the "default" folder from App_Data/Sites/... and install a new Orchard everything runs perfectly, no exception and the modules are ok, but when I change the connection string to point to SQL Server again, the same exception happens again.

Any assistance in this matter will be highly appreciated,

Regards and thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not SQL Server that's causing the error, but corrupted data. There is a feature that should be enabled but is not. I bet it's this one: `BodyLogic.LegacyDb`.

You probably added a dependency to an *already enabled* feature, am I right? If so then what you see is the default behavior - Orchard won't auto enable the newly added dependency. You need to do that manually.

Feature enable/disable state is stored in the db table `Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord`. To fix the error:

- open it,
- find a record with `Name` equal to `BodyLogic.LegacyDb` and
- set both `InstallState` and `EnableState` values to `Up`

After you've done that

- clear your `App_Data/cache.dat`,
- restart the app pool and you're set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything you described is exactly what I did. But when I went into the DB the row was not there and then I added "BodyLogic.LegacyDB" to both tables (Settings_ShellFeatureRecord & Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord) manually but the problem persist. Any suggestions?

Comment: Mind the case - from the error it looks like the name is `BodyLogic.LegacyDb`, not `BodyLogic.LegacyDB`.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly!... It was a space at the end, the case was right.